# pattern matching in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, function

I need to substring "test" from my variable "5.myname (test)" in postgresql
I am able to extract number[i.e 5] and text [i.e myname] from above string but unable to extract test. can anyone please suggest pattern to extract test from above string.

Comment: put your attempts to the question please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT substring('5.myname (test)' from '\((.*)\)');
```